# JQuery UI dialog not passing form variables after preventdefault

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-ui, dialog

I believe I'm doing something wrong here.  I have a Perl script that says "if not submit button name submit/save, display html page.  Then on submit, run subroutines which pretty much insert6/update data to the db.

```
if ($cgi->param("group_submit") eq '') {
    &display_add_promo();
    exit(0);
} else {
    &group_product($group_id);
    my $group_page = "./group?group_id=$group_id";
            print $cgi->redirect($group_page);
            &close_and_exit;
  }
exit(0);
```

Now using JQuery I check if a "product from the new promotion code assigned is contained within the old promotion code assigned and if so through an alert.

```
\$('#dialog').dialog({
            height: 270,
            width: 500,
            autoOpen: false,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                    'Continue': function(event) {
                            \$(event.target).css({opacity: 0.25}).unbind();
                            \$('#my_form').unbind('submit').submit();
                            \$(this).dialog('close');
                    },
                    'Cancel': function(event) {
                            \$(event.target).css({opacity: 0.25}).unbind();
                            \$(this).dialog('close');
                    }
            }
});

\$('#my_form').submit(function(event) {

            \$.each(\$('#new_products').val().split(''), function(i, char) {
                    var existing = \$('#existing_products').val();

                    if (existing.indexOf(char) != -1) {
                            event.preventDefault();
                            \$('#dialog').dialog('open');
                    }
            });

});
```

Now when the dialog comes up and I hit "Continue" the script posts, but to the same page so says mozilla web console and none of my Perl logic runs and it basically seems like the page just refreshes.  Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this to simulate the submit click and run all of my pending logic on submit was:

```
$('.group_submit').trigger('click');
```